# how to run vb exe file from java server side with parameters

Tags: java, maven, server

I am writing a java server process that in addition should run vb.exe file with parameters in windows only.

I tried to use ProcessBuilder with start function and Process with exec function but I have no error but nothing happens!

the cmd for example:

```
"C:\AL500\BIAFLABEL\AddToQueue.exe" "C:\AL500\BiafLabel\Templates\2.xml" -printer \\mickaelbpc\System-N
```

the command line definitions in the code:

```
String fullcmd = "\"C:\\AL500\\BIAFLABEL\\AddToQueue.exe\" \"C:\\AL500\\BiafLabel\\Templates\\2.xml\" -printer \\\\mickaelbpc\\System-N";
String fullcmd1 = "C:\\AL500\\BIAFLABEL\\AddToQueue.exe C:\\AL500\\BiafLabel\\Templates\\2.xml -printer \\\\mickaelbpc\\System-N";
String cmd1 = "C:\\AL500\\BIAFLABEL\\AddToQueue.exe";
String cmd2 = "C:\\AL500\\BiafLabel\\Templates\\2.xml";
String cmd3 = "-printer";
String cmd4 = "\\\\mickaelbpc\\System-N";   
String[] command = new String[]{cmd1, cmd2, cmd3,cmd4};
```

1. Process + array:

   ```
   File dir = new File("C:/workspace");
   Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, dir);
   process.waitFor();
   InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
   InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
   String strData;
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

   BufferedReader brData = new BufferedReader(new 
   InputStreamReader(stdout));
   while ((strData = brData.readLine()) != null)
   {
        sb = sb.append(strData).append("\r\n");
   }
   brData.close();
   ```
2. ProcessBuilder + string command with ":

   ```
   ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(fullcmd);
   pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
   Process process1=pb.start();
   BufferedReader inStreamReader = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(process1.getInputStream())); 
   String line;
   while (true) {
       line = inStreamReader.readLine();
       if (line == null) { break; }
       System.out.println(line);
   ```
3. ProcessBuilder + string command with no ":

   ```
    File log = new File("log"); 
    ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(/*command*/fullcmd1);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
    Process process1=pb.start();
    BufferedReader inStreamReader = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(process1.getInputStream())); 
    String line;
    while (true) {
         line = inStreamReader.readLine();
         if (line == null) { break; }
              System.out.println(line);
         }
   ```

   after the changes I am getting this **error**: "java.io.**IOException**: Cannot run program "C:\AL500\BIAFLABEL\AddToQueue.exe C:\AL500\BiafLabel\Templates\2.xml -printer \mickaelbpc\System-N": **CreateProcess error=2**, The system cannot find the file specified" can you please advise?
4. ProcessBuilder with cmd.exe:

   ```
   ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c",fullcmd);
   pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
   Process process1=pb.start();
   BufferedReader inStreamReader = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(process1.getInputStream())); 
   String line;
   while (true) {
           line = inStreamReader.readLine();
           if (line == null) { break; }
           System.out.println(line);
    }
   ```

I did all the options and more...if it will be necessary I will add more examples

the vb exe should print a file. any idea how to run it from java process? or what is wrong with my code?

Comment: As i understand process builder, you should not concatenate parameters in the command string, but passing each parameter as independent argument. Have you tried to `ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(command);`

Comment: Is this executable supposed to run on the server or the client?

Comment: Alexandre Cartapanis: I tried it but the same result - no error and nothing happen.

Comment: Andrew Thompson: how can I check it?  I run the same command line in command prompt and it works. the problem is only when I am doing it on java server

Answer (score 0):

1. Study the error and output stream of the command. Need to redirect them and stream them in a separate thread. Or try this fronm

   File log = new File("log");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
2. Is the full path correct? Can you print the commad line space seperated to a file called run.cmd and run that manually and see what happens from prompt?
3. which directory are you starting the process from might have to be different than the one that your java program is running at? Process builder has a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory()

To know which directory your java program is using do this:

```
File f = new File("./");
try{
    System.out.println("Start dir is :" + f.getCanonicalFile());
}catch...
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalFile()

4. i do not think you do not need to add quotes, just set them in the array with actual values. but if running from a .cmd you will need to qualify params with spaces by putting quotes. best to have no spaces in the paths or params when testing.

See github.com/tgkprog/nli/blob/master/RunCmd.java if ur redirecting to log, dont get the stream again in your loop. and dont call via cmd.exe. in my example ignore the actual commmand, put ur exe and params, i just called a sh file as on ubuntu. You call with your 4 params

Comment: about your answer: 1.  the log file is empty but nothing happenns

Comment: 2. I put the command line (C:\AL500\BIAFLABEL\AddToQueue.exe C:\AL500\BiafLabel\Templates\2.xml -printer \\mickaelbpc\System-N) in run.cmd file and it works manually but I must the spaces

Comment: 3. the pb.directory() is null - this means to use the working directory of the current Java process. the current directory is: C:\eclipse and I can run the command line manually from this folder.  do you have an idea or another solution?

Comment: Can you show your full code as it is now? only thing i can think of is the handing of the streams (input, output and error stream) If not done properly processes can hang

Comment: process.waitFor(); move this to after you have set up the process fully If possible put ur class in github so its runnable and easy to see full file(s)

Comment: attached is the code in https://github.com/stleibowitz/nli link. thank you for your help!

Comment: see https://github.com/tgkprog/nli/blob/master/RunCmd.java if ur redirecting to log, dont get the stream again in your loop. and dont call via cmd.exe. in my example ignore the actual commmand, put ur exe and params, i just called a sh file as on ubuntu. You call with your correct 4 params